# SSRS - Uploading a Report and copying to a network directory

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We are using SSRS and when we "Upload" an .rdl file using the web report manager we would like to automatically take a copy of that .rdl file and put it on a network drive.

I'm not familiar with SSRS at all and I don't even know where to begin to look.  I'm assuming that there is an .API.

Is there a way to capture via the web report manager after the file has been uploaded to the DB that I can then make a copy of that rdl file to the network path of my choosing?

**Update:**
It appears that Microsoft doesn't allow customization of the Report Manager.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157147(v=sql.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157147%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

So maybe the answer is that I can't do what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you are asking using Report Manager. However you can use the rs.exe utility provided with Reporting Services to create a script that will download the rdl file(s) from the report server to disk.

Example here: http://blog.geektrainer.com/2012/04/download-all-reports.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I know the owner of this blog.  Thank you pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to keep the back up of the SSRS reports. [Here](http://www.sqlmusings.com/2011/03/28/how-to-download-all-your-ssrs-report-definitions-rdl-files-using-powershell/)  is the link which downloads the file to your local drive. You can modify the same for copying to the network location if you want.